# Divide a NSString by specific characters

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making an app to help students study, but I'm having trouble. The app lets you make notes between other things, but I need help to make my code work. I'm trying to divide a `NSString` into to by a specific character for example the user writes in a note "Dolphins : are cetacean mammals closely..." I need the app to recognize the character : and also the part thats on the left it needs to be save to use later, as a variable and the part of the right also but as a different variable so I can use them later.
right now im doing it like this

```
NSArray *card = [_argumentTextView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]; 

QueRes *make = [QueRes sharedInstance];

make.question = card [0];
make.response = card [1];
```

But, when I use the variable question and the variable response it appears blank or it doesn't have anything. I use the variable like this:

```
QueRes *make = [QueRes sharedInstance];
_questionTextView.text = make.question;
```

btw the method I use to declare the variables is:

in the h

```
@interface PreRes : NSObject

{
    NSString *_response;
    NSString *_question;     
}

*+* (PreRes *)sharedInstance;

@property(strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *question;   
@property(strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *response;

@end
```

and in the m

```
@implementation QueRes  

@synthesize response = _response;
@synthesize question = _question;

+ (QueRes *)sharedInstance 
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static QueRes *instance = nil;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[QueRes alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}

- (id)init  
 {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) 
    { 
        _question = nil;
        _response = nil;
    }


    return self;
 }
@end
```

Comment: Set two breakpoints after the QueRes *make = [QueRes sharedInstance]; lines and make sure that the variable "make" is the same thing both times. If it's nil, or a different value, then something is wrong with your sharedInstance logic.

Comment: Also make sure that `_questionTextView` isn't `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting strings in Objective-C/Cocoa can be done with these two methods on NSString:

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator;
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)separator;
```

From the documentation of `componentsSeparatedByString:`:

---

The substrings in the array appear in the order they did in the receiver. Adjacent occurrences of the separator string produce empty strings in the result. Similarly, if the string begins or ends with the separator, the first or last substring, respectively, is empty. For example, this code fragment:

```
NSString *list = @"Norman, Stanley, Fletcher";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

produces an array `{ @"Norman", @"Stanley", @"Fletcher" }.`

If list begins with a comma and space—for example, ", Norman, Stanley, Fletcher"—the array has these contents: `{ @"", @"Norman", @"Stanley", @"Fletcher" }`

If list has no separators—for example, "Norman"—the array contains the string itself, in this case `{ @"Norman" }`.

---

These two methods are really not intended for robust text processing tasks though.  You should probably look into the following APIs:

```
- (void)enumerateLinguisticTagsInRange:(NSRange)range 
                               scheme:(NSString *)tagScheme 
                              options:(NSLinguisticTaggerOptions)opts 
                          orthography:(NSOrthography *)orthography 
                           usingBlock:(void (^)(NSString *tag, NSRange tokenRange, NSRange sentenceRange, BOOL *stop))block;

- (void)enumerateSubstringsInRange:(NSRange)range 
                           options:(NSStringEnumerationOptions)opts
                        usingBlock:(void (^)(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop))block;
```

---

Also, be aware that blindly accessing array items returned by `componentsSeparatedByString:` will crash with an index out of range exception if `componentsSeparatedByString:` returns less items than you expect.  As will be the case if the string lacks a semi-colon in the code you posted above.

You should be validating that the array returned is the correct/expected length.  Eg:

```
if ([card count] >= 2)
{
    make.question = card[0];
    make.response = card[1];
}
```

From your question though I think your problem probably lies with your "singleton" rather than your string splitting logic.

Comment: im sorry im a little new in Objective c, what do you mean by singleton

Comment: I added the method i use to make the variables if that help you helping me finding the problem @orj